# Saving text and audio from flash using AS3 and PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, audio, text

I need to save audio files from user and give it a unique name. The code for audio is working but I haven't succeeded in sending a filename. Any suggestions?

flash code:

```
function onSave():void
{
soundO.position=0;
testAudio=enco.encode(soundO,1);
file.save(testAudio,Subject+".wav");

var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest('upload.php');
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
req.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
req.data = testAudio;
loader.load(req);
}
```

PHP code

```
<?php
$fp = fopen( 'filename.wav', 'wb' );
fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('php://input'));
fclose( $fp );
?>
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: Check out this my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830721/send-file-from-actionscript-to-servlet/18830921#18830921

Comment: As an alternative the filename could simply be passed as a query string parameter.