# How post extra name value pairs with a binary data post in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Here I upload recorded sound to server, but I need to add file name and the user name who is uploading the file. But I don't know how I can to post extra name value pairs with a binary data post?

```
function onClick(e:MouseEvent)
{
   var sba:ByteArray = mp3Encoder.mp3Data; 
   var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(URL);
   req.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
   req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
   req.data = sba;           
   var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
   loader.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler );
   loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler );
   loader.load( req );
}
```

Comment: You could either build a proper multipart request, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830721/send-file-from-actionscript-to-servlet/18830921#18830921, or simply pass the values in the URL as query parameters.

Comment: I missed your comment, you already point to that answer )

Answer (score 0):

To do something like that you're likely going to have to use a URLRequest header, check out this information here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestHeader.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multipart` request for sending both types of data (binary and variables). Check out this answer about how to create it in AS3:

[Send file from actionscript to servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830721/send-file-from-actionscript-to-servlet/18830921#18830921)