# Making an HTTP POST request in as3 AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air, httprequest

I am trying to make an HTTP POST request through as3 AIR for mobile equivalent to this curl request :

```
curl -d '{"firstname": "John", "lastname": “Doe"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://eve-demo.herokuapp.com/people
```

This is my code :

```
var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
urlVariables.firstname = "Jhon";
urlVariables.lastname = "Doe";

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
request.url = "http://eve-demo.herokuapp.com/people";
request.contentType = "multipart/form-data";
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
request.data = urlVariables;

var contentTypeHeader:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
var acceptHeader:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
var formDataHeader:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

request.requestHeaders = [acceptHeader, formDataHeader];

postLoader = new URLLoader();
postLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
postLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler);
postLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
postLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
postLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

try
{
    postLoader.load(request);
}
catch (error:Error)
{
    trace("Unable to load post URL");
}
```

But I am getting following error :

```
[HTTPStatusHandler]: [HTTPStatusEvent type="httpStatus" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 status=400 redirected=false responseURL=null]
[IOErrorHandler]: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://eve-demo.herokuapp.com/people" errorID=2032]
```

Anyone has any suggestions how to make an http post request with 'multiform/form-data' (without any file to upload) ??

Thanks

Comment: check out that answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830721/send-file-from-actionscript-to-servlet/18830921#18830921

Comment: this may work if I want to upload a file but what if I just want to send these 2 variables as a POST request ??

Comment: just skip _byteArray_, it can be null, or if you don't need _contentType = "multipart/form-data"_ you can just skip it to set as well (the default value is  _"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"_)

Comment: Now the http status error code is 422 !!!

Answer (score 0):

`URLVariables` is intended to be used with url-encoded variables, not JSON. Try setting the `data` to a JSON string:

```
var params:Object = { firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe" };
request.data = JSON.stringify(params);
```

Comment: Nope still not working.. same error with HTTP status 400

Comment: Are you sure that the parameters are valid for that web service?

Comment: Yup, the service is a demo of python eve framework, you can use it too !!

Comment: Ok. I ask because I tried it and found that if you omit the parameters the data is returned. Where is the relevant documentation?

Comment: Here : http://python-eve.org/features.html

I am not being much helpful with this REST api & HTTP request stuff as I am new to this..!